# How did Asajj Ventress hack Savage Opress?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

If you look at this video, Asajj Ventress hacked Savage Opress merely by touching his head. This is more impressive than Jedi Mind Tricks.

But, how did she do it? Is this some Sith power as she was trained in Sith arts by Dooku himself? This is surprising because I thought Sith didn't have powers to control others. If yes, what is its name? And, why didn't she use this power more often?

Comment: "Asajj Ventress hacked Savage Opress merely by touching his head. This is more impressive than Jedi Mind Tricks" — is it? Obi-wan didn't even need to touch those Stormtroopers.

Comment: Cn you explain what you mean by 'Hacked'? I can't view the video right now, so I'm missing context as to whether you mean "hacked to pieces" or "hacked into a computer".

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I compared it with Jedi Mind Tricks. She took control of him.

Comment: It still makes me think that Savage Opress is a computer/robot though?

Answer (score 1):

Savage's origin story in episode 13 ("Monster") of season 3 explains this.

> **TL;DR** He's a sleeper agent.
>  Savage Opress comes from Dathomir. On this planet, males (Nightbrothers) were subservient to, usually more force-sensitive, females (Nightsisters). Asaji Ventress is one of the Nightsisters.
>  To makes matters worse, he was specifically selected by Ventress to be sent as a sleeper-agent apprentice to Dooku. For this, he went through a gruesome contest and then was thoroughly brainwashed by Nightsisters' dark magic.
>  So, Ventress didn't just "hack" him with a single touch. She merely activated his previous programming.
>  See an [article about him on Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Savage_Opress) and/or [his transformation scene on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPN4SJ_AP8c&ab_channel=FulcrumFanEdits).